# Aparece apenas registros com coluna contendo x palavra

Tags: php

Estou com um sistema de postagem feito: o usuário faz a postagem e quando a mesma contem uma # seguida de uma palavra, a palavra automaticamente é adiciona em outra coluna com uma virgula.
Exemplo de post:

> Bom #Dia pessoal do @Stackoverflow, poderiam me #ajudar ?

Exemplo de registro na tabela:

> id: 1, post: Bom #Dia pessoal do @Stackoverflow, poderiam me #ajudar ?, author: Raphael, hashtags: dia,ajudar

Só que estou montando uma página para aparecer apenas postagens contendo hashtag x.

Preciso de um código que mostre apenas os registros que contém a palavra x dentro da coluna `hashtags`.

Exemplo: Preciso que mostre todos os registros que contém a palavra bom na coluna `hashtags`.

> id: 1, post: Poderiam me #ajudar, aliás, #bom #dia!, author: Raphael, hashtags: ajudar,bom,dia
>
> id: 2, post: #Boa #noite pessoal do @Stackoverflow, poderiam me #ajudar ?, author: Raphael, hashtags: boa,noite,ajudar
>
> id: 3, post: #Bom #fds pessoal do @Stackoverflow, poderiam me #ajudar ?, author: Raphael, hashtags: bom,fds,ajudar

Então o sistema irá mostrar apenas os registros com id 1 e 3 por conterem a palavra bom dentro da coluna `hashtags`.

Comment: Será que este código ajuda?  $str = '#helloworld #test #video #youtube Bon Iver are the best daily surprise :D';
    
    preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches);
    
    $hashtags = implode(',', $matches[1]);
    
    var_dump($hashtags);

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco mais como você quer? Não deu pra entender muito bem, deixe exemplos, se possível. Veja também [ask]

Comment: @miltoncamara Não é para mostrar às palavras sem a # e sim mostrar os registros que contém ela dentro da coluna `hashtags`.

Comment: @Raphael, agora entendii, você quer fazer essa consulta no MySql? Qual banco você está utilizando?

Answer (score 2):

Para efetuar um pesquisa por determinada palavra utiliza-se o caractere coringa: % (Porcentagem)

Para pesquisar a palavra, estando ela no inicio, meio ou fim.

```
select * from NOMEDATABELA where hashtags like '%bom%'
```